# Selenium,Python throws " ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_116.0.5845" this error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_116.0.5845
```

> My chrome version:116.0.5845.179, Selenium==4.12.0

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
This version :116.0.5845 isn't available in the official site

Works fine in firefox and edge browsers
Note:

1. Tried degrading the chrome but its auto updated
2. Tried giving all stable versions in chromedriver manager :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager(version="114.0.5735.16").install(), options=chrome_options)
```

3. Tried adding service too:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

I want to run in chrome with latest version of chrome
Tried all solution from all sites and from stackoverflow

Comment: Are you sure you have selenium version is `4.12.0`? Can you double check.

Comment: Yeh @Shawn .I have recently updated and rechecked again.